# NetSuite Contract Handling Alternatives

Tags: netsuite, contract

I’m looking for ideas or suggestions for NetSuite relating to contract handling. My current understanding of how NetSuite handles contracts is the Sales order sits at the top and the contracts associated with that/created with the Sales Order. In this scenario I need the contract to exist independently or “Top Level” then track multiple Orders/Shipments/Fulfillment against contract. I have yet to locate a SuiteApp or 3rd party SAAS that can Tie into NetSuite to meet these requirements.